# How to pass arguments to perl when trying to change a line?

Tags: files, perl, arguments

I am using the approach suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/434051/how-to-replace-a-string-on-the-5th-line-of-multiple-text-files to modify the first line of an archive. Let's suppose the first line in `file.txt` is

```
keepme=change1me
```

And I want to obtain

```
keepme=newstring
```

The issue is that newstring is stored in var1

I tried:

```
var1=newstring
perl -i -pe 's/(keepme=)(.*)/$1${var1}/ if $.==1' ../file.txt
perl ${var1} -i -pe 's/(keepme=)(.*)/$1$ARGV[0]/ if $.==1' ../file.txt
```

In both cases the result is

```
keepme=
```

If I do

```
perl -i -pe ${var1} 's/(keepme=)(.*)/$1$ARGV[0]/ if $.==1' ../file.txt
Can't open s/(genome1=)(.*)/$1$ARGV[0]wq/ if $.==1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your first attempt, you want `${var1}` expanded by the shell, and all other `$` variables protected from it (so that Perl expands them instead):

```
perl -i -pe "s/(keepme=)(.*)/\$1${var1}/ if \$. == 1" ../file.txt
```

The double quotes, rather than single quotes, make it so that Perl receives `newstring` instead of the variable name, and escaping the other dollar signs with backslashes makes the shell pass them through untouched.

Answer (score 2):

To access the environment variable in Perl you can use $ENV{var1}.

To do this you can export the variable, this will mean the variable is set until you unset it:

> export var1=newstring
>
> perl -i -pe 's/(keepme=)(.*)/$1$ENV{var1}/ if $.==1' ../file.txt

Alternatively if you only want to set the variable to be used by the Perl command when you execute it, you can assign it in front of your command:

> var1=newstring2 perl -i -pe 's/(keepme=)(.*)/$1$ENV{var1}/ if $.==1' ../file.txt