# How to pass a path to a file through a call to perl from bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, quoting

This is a more advanced version of a previous question
([How to pass arguments to perl when trying to change a line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189365/how-to-pass-arguments-to-perl-when-trying-to-change-a-line))  I made.

This time I am trying to pass a path, but evertything seems that the the perl script is readin the / wrongly.

Suppose the line 4 in file.txt looks like this

```
 path_root_abs = "/path/to/thefile"
```

To obtain the working directory and replace it in /path/to/file I did

```
 directory=`pwd`
 perl -i -pe "s/(path_root_abs\s=\s\")(.*)(\")/\$1${directory}$3/ if \$. == 4" file.txt
```

And got:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/(path_root_abs\s=\s")(.*)(")/$1/scratch"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/(path_root_abs\s=\s")(.*)(")/$1/scratch"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What should I do to avoid unix reading the \ that comes after scratch as a bareword.

Comment: If I add a \ before ${directory} the file.txt is changed to path_root_abs = ""

Comment: Note that, if you might have more than one space, or no space, before or after the `=`, you should use `\s*`. (And you need to use `\s` rather than a plain space if the file might have tabs in it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that `$directory` contains slashes which are also being used as the delimiter for the substitution operator (`s///`). Basically, if `$directory` is `/home/je_b`, what Perl sees is:

```
 perl -i -pe "s/foo//home/jb/ if \$. == 4" file.txt
```

It takes the `/` of `/home` as the second `/` of the `s///` operator. The simplest solution is to use a different character instead of `/`:

```
perl -i -pe "s#foo#${directory}#" file.txt
```

You can also simplify in other ways though. Consider this:

```
perl -pe "s#(path_root_abs = \")(.*)#\1${directory}\"# if \$. == 4" file
```

- There's no need for `\s` when you only need to match one space, just use a 
  space.
- Perl's substitution operator understands both `$1` and `\1` so use the latter and avoid escaping.
- There's no point in capturing the `"` character. If you know it's there, add it yourself.

Finally, you could also get the `pwd` from Perl directly. Perl has access to all exported shell variables through the `%ENV` hash. So, you could just do:

```
perl -pe 's#(path_root_abs = ").*#$1$ENV{PWD}"# if $.==1' file
```